# How to display list of names while typing @ in textbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, I have one textbox and while writing message if we type @ then it should display list of names which is in arraylist.
Kindly help how can I do this feature using angularjs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

first you should publish what you have tried so far.. then only will help us to help you further...

here i wrote search alone..

for string specific,

you have to write function inside `ng-change="func_name(your_txt)"`

read the text use `substr` to find whether your text contains `@` if its do filter.. here i wrote filter inside ng-repeat can write filter on change will answer.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Angular animated search box - sibeeshpassion </title>  
    <style>  
        .inputText {  
            border: 1px solid #ccc;  
            border-radius: 10px;  
            background-color: #0ff;  
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;  
            width: 230px;  
            height: 30px;  
        }  
  
        ul {  
            list-style: none;  
            padding: 10px;  
            background-color: #CAEAF5;  
            border-radius: 10px;  
            border: 1px solid #ccc;  
            width: 210px;  
        }  
  
        li {  
            border: 1px solid #ccc;  
            border-right: none;  
            border-left: none;  
            padding: 2px;  
            text-align: center;  
        }         
    </style>  
</head>  
<body ng-app ng-init="placesVisited=['Delhi','Kerala','Tamil Nadu','Banglore','Uttar Pradesh','Noida','Haryana','Thrissur'];">  
    <div>  
        <input type="text" ng-change="do_on_at(curPlace)" ng-model="curPlace" class="inputText">  
        <ul>  
            <li  ng-repeat="place in placesVisited | filter:curPlace">  
                <span>{{place}} </span>  
            </li>  
        </ul>  
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```